# распарсить ответ от сервера XML

Tags: c#, xml, xmlparser

От сервера приходит ответ:

```
<DicResult>
    <head />
    <def pos="прилагательное">
        <text>глупый</text>
        <tr pos="прилагательное">
            <text>дурацкий</text>
            <syn pos="прилагательное">
                <text>идиотский</text>
            </syn>
            <syn pos="прилагательное">
                <text>идиотический</text>
            </syn>
        </tr>
        <tr pos="прилагательное">
            <text>безумный</text>
            <syn pos="прилагательное">
                <text>безрассудный</text>
            </syn>
            <syn pos="прилагательное">
                <text>малоумный</text>
            </syn>
        </tr>
        <tr pos="причастие">
            <text>ограниченный</text>
        </tr>
    </def>
</DicResult>
```

Нужно получить самую первую часть речи т.е. "прилагательное", у меня получилось вывести только список всех слов.

Comment: Хотелось бы уточнить, что вы понимаете под фразой «получить самую первую часть речи». Тогда ответ можно будет подкрепить примерами.